# mysql append inserted data to column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure if this is even possible in sql.

I have the following tables:

- "documents" containing the columns id and authors
- "authors" containing the columns id, initial and lastname
- "authorships" containing the columns id, document_id and author_id

Documents can have multiple authors.

I need the authors column in the documents table to include the last name and intial from the authors table, formatted accordingly:

"Bloggs, J. Doe, J. Punchclock, P. Botts, D." etc...

for example:

**documents**

```
| id  | title             | authors |
-------------------------------------
| 1   | Arms and the Man  |         |
| 2   | East of Eden      |         |
| 3   | If Not Now, When? |         |
```

**authors**

```
| id  | initial | lastname     |
--------------------------------
| 1   | J       | Bloggs       |
| 2   | J       | Doe          |
| 3   | P       | Punchclock   |
| 4   | D       | Botts        |
```

**authorships**

```
| id  | document_id  | author_id |
----------------------------------
| 1   | 1            | 1         |
| 2   | 1            | 2         |
| 3   | 1            | 3         |
| 4   | 2            | 3         |
| 5   | 2            | 4         |
| 6   | 3            | 1         |
| 7   | 3            | 3         |
| 8   | 3            | 4         |
```

I would need the authors column in the documents table to be updated to:

```
| id  | title             | authors                             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1   | Arms and the Man  | Bloggs, J. Doe, J. Punchclock, P.   |
| 2   | East of Eden      | Punchclock, P. Botts, D.            |
| 3   | If Not Now, When? | Bloggs, J. Punchclock, P. Botts, D. |
```

If possible I need an sql statement to be ables to do this - that appends multiple values to one column ?

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions, and why they didn't work**

Comment: So, you are intentionally de-normalizing your data.  Is there a reason for this? You can easily return the data in the format you are looking for from a query without having to store author to document relationships in two places.

Comment: If you already have a many to many table called authorships why do you need to duplicate that info in the documents table?

Everything you need to display on the front end can be accomplished with the right query on the authorships table as is.

Comment: I have to get the data in a format to work with an old system as a temporary solution... I know its not correct / best practice but required for the time being :(

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I agree and appreciate that I could have added attempted solutions, however I disagree that this question is unclear or not useful. 

I deliberately tried to make the question as simple and straightforward as possible to quickly get the answer I require (which I got), in turn also helping others quickly get an answer - therefore not cluttering the post with any unnecessary content / solutions that do not work etc...

Please consider this re your vote, and I will try to add more "attempted solutions" in future posts / questions.

Sorry for any inconvenience, Jon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to concatenate lastname and initial, then [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to put multiple results on one line.

```
select d.id, d.title, 
group_concat(concat(a.lastname,', ', a.initial, '.') 
             order by a.lastname, a.initial separator ' ') authors
from documents d
inner join authorships ash on ash.document_id = d.id
inner join authors a on ash.author_id = a.id
group by d.id, d.title
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2b39/13)